# Without taking the real values can it be solved with the help of any inequalities?

Tags: inequality

Let $n$ be a positive real mumber and $p$ be a positive integer. Which of the
following inequalities is true?
(A) $n^{p}>\frac{(n+1)^{p+1}-n^{p+1}}{p+1}$
(B) $n^{p}<\frac{(n+1)^{p+1}-n^{p+1}}{p+1}$
(C) $(n+1)^{p}<\frac{(n+1)^{p+1}-n^{p+1}}{p+1}$
(D) none of the above.

Comment: Have you tried using the binomial theorem? That would help you decide (A) and (B). For (C), note that $n = p = 1$ is a counterexample.

Comment: yeah I got the ans but I was in seek of direct proof of this inequality

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\begin{align}(n+1)^{p+1} - n^{p+1} &= \left(n^{p+1} + \dbinom{p+1}{1}n^p + \cdots + 1\right) - n^{p+1}\\
&=  \dbinom{p+1}{1}n^p + \cdots + 1 \\
&> \dbinom{p+1}{1}n^p & (\because n > 0) \\
&= (p+1)n^p.\end{align}$$

Thus,

$$n^p < \dfrac{(n+1)^{p+1} - n^{p+1}}{p+1}.$$

This lets you decide the truth value of (A) and (B).

---

(C) is false. This can be seen by considering $n = p = 1$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. To show that an option is false, it suffices to show that there's at least one $(n, p)$ which contradicts its truth value. So by considering $(1, 1)$, we see that (A) and (C) are false and that's done.

Comment: if u put n=p=1 clearly b will come! no more option will satisfy.

Comment: But that isn't enough to conclude that (B) is true for **all** values of $(n, p)$. To conclude that, you need a proof like above.

Comment: yes.That's what i asking for.